# How can I tell whether or not a molecule is planar?

Tags: organic-chemistry, molecular-structure

I am doing several questions involving judgment on the planarity of a compound.

> Which of the following is not a planar molecule?
>
> 1. $\ce{H_2C=C=CH_2}$
> 2. $\ce{H_2C=C=C=CH_2}$
> 3. $\ce{H_2C=C=O}$
> 4. $\ce{NC-HC=CH-CN}$

I had the idea that the compound in with central atom has $\ce{sp}$ hybridisation is planar or the compound in which all the atoms has the same hybridization. But it is not working in this case. I am aware of finding out the hybridization of a atom in a compound but I feel trapped to decide the planarity of certain compounds. The [question](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/4399) does not address this purpose.  Anyone has any idea to solve this and many related questions?

Comment: For an sp hybridized atom, the p orbitals that are used to form pi bonds will be perpendicular. That makes the pi bonds formed either side of an sp atom perpendicular to each other.

Comment: The answer to your question is here: [Why are the two CH2 groups in allene perpendicular to each other?](http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/49670/why-are-the-two-ch2-groups-in-allene-perpendicular-to-each-other)

Comment: Unfortunately, I think the answer to the general question is: learn chemistry. Because there are all sorts of factors that influence geometry...

Comment: @orthocresol can you give reference  to some other questions whee this problem has been discussed

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think these general rules work:

1. If there is an $\ce{sp^3}$ hybridized carbon (or nitrogen), the molecular is NOT planar.

2) If there are no $\ce{sp^3}$ hybridized carbons (or nitrogens), and there is only one $\ce{sp^2}$ hybridized atom (carbon or nitrogen), it will be planar.

3) If there are no $\ce{sp^3}$ hybridized atoms, and there are 2 $\ce{sp^2}$ hybridized atoms (carbon or nitrogen) that are separated by an even number of double bonds and no single bonds, then the molecule will not be planar.

So a general simple rule is that:

> the molecule will not be planar if there is an $\ce{sp^3}$ hybridized carbon (or nitrogen) atom or two $\ce{sp^2}$ hybridized atoms of carbon/nitrogen which are separated by an even number of double bonds and no single bonds. Otherwise, its structure allows it to be planar.

Even though the molecule will have a structure that allows for it to exist in a planar conformation, there may be some/many that do not persist in a planar conformation due to steric effects, or complex three dimensional geometries.

---

In the problems you listed above, using this rule:

1. Not planar because there are no $\ce{sp^3}$ and the two $\ce{sp^2}$s are separated by an even number of double bonds.
2. Planar because there are two $\ce{sp^2}$s but they are separated by an odd number of double bonds (3) (and no single bonds)
3. Planar because there are no $\ce{sp^3}$s and only 1 $\ce{sp^2}$s that make 3 or more bonds (C or N).  The orbital geometry is NOT planar because the $\ce{sp^2}$ oxygen is separated from the $\ce{sp^2}$ carbon by an even number of double bonds.
4. Planar because 2 $\ce{sp^2}$s are separated by an odd number (1) of double bonds (and no single bonds)

Comment: I think these rules would make $\ce{C60}$ planar...

Comment: True.  Interesting point.  C60 might be described as having approximately planar geometry-it is basically a planar sheet cut and contorted into a spheroid.

Comment: Butatriene (which is listed above in the problem) is planar but that doesn't mean that the hydrogens will not be contorted out of plane.

Comment: Basically C60 is contorted graphite

Comment: I find that claim dubious, but instead of dwelling on that, here's another one. How about biphenyl? Planar or non-planar?

Comment: Biphenyl is only conformationally aplanar because of steric  interaction.

Comment: Also, in both C60 and other aromatics, there are not really any carbon-carbon single bonds and not really any carbon-carbon double bonds, so they are allowed to be a-planar by the rules above because no two SP2 hybridized carbons are separated by an odd number of double bonds.

Comment: Exactly, and steric interactions do a lot in terms of conformations that you haven't accounted for here. I'm just saying this is super-complicated.

Comment: Since Benzene is planar we can see that the bonds between two carbon atoms can not be defined as double bonds, but your example of biphenyl gives me an idea for an exception that does violate the letter of the rules.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/49451/discussion-between-joseph-hirsch-and-zhe).

Comment: I am a little bit confused.According to [this link](http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/49670/why-are-the-two-ch2-groups-in-allene-perpendicular-to-each-other)a) is not planar but according to your rules,it is the other way.Also you mentioned in your answer that butatriene is non planar but in your comments,you mentioned it as planar.Please resolve the issue.Thanks.

Comment: Sorry, I got my evens and odds reversed in the prior edit.  I have fixed them as well as the answers.  So basically if two SP2s are separated by an odd number of double bonds (1, 3 etc) then their single bonds will be in the same plane, but if they are separated by an even number of double bonds (with no single bonds in between) they will be rotated $90^o$

Comment: Note that b) butatriene is "textbook" planar, (it is a line of carbons with hydrogen fishtails), the hydrogens will have a tendancy to get twisted out of the same plane.

Comment: Likewise d) 1, 2 dicyanoethylene (both forms) is textbook planar but has a trans and a cis form and the cis form will probably twist mildly out of plane.

Comment: http://pubs.acs.org/doi/abs/10.1021/ed082p1329

Comment: Shouldn't then [10]-Annulene be planar(all sp2, no sp3)?